# Create spatial joined table with intersected geometry using ST_Intersects and ST_Intersection in PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, st-intersects, psycopg2

I want to perform a spatial intersection join of the two tables "temperature_precipation_slope" and "buek200_clc10 with `ST_Intersects` in PostGIS via `psycopg2` in Python and write the result in the created table `gis_data`. Then, I want to calculate the areas of all rows in gis_data with `ST_Area` (this part is still commented out in the code). Afterward, I want to write the joined table into a `DataFrame` or `GeoDataFrame` to further progress the data and save the data as a GeoPackage or Shapefile in the end. Therefore, I need the column `geom` in the table `gis_data`.

This is the relevant part of my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

# =============================================================================
# Spatial join of GIS Data in PostGIS and transfer to GeoDataFrame
# =============================================================================

perform_spatial_join = True

if perform_spatial_join == True:
    print('spatial join of GIS data in PostGIS is processing')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='gis_data', user='postgres', password=***, port=5432)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE gis_data AS SELECT tps.precipitat, tps.temperatur, tps.slope, bc.tkle_nr, bc.clc From "temperature_precipation_slope" tps, "buek200_clc10" bc WHERE ST_Intersects(tps.geom, bc.geom);'
    cur.execute(sql)
    print('spatial join of GIS data complete')
    # sql = 'ALTER TABLE gis_data ADD COLUMN area double precision;'
    # cur.execute(sql)
    # sql = 'UPDATE gis_data SET area  = Round(ST_AREA(geom)::numeric,2);'
    # cur.execute(sql)    
gis_data = gpd.read_postgis('select precipitat, temperatur, slope, tkle_nr, clc, geom from "gis_data"', conn, geom_col='geom', crs=25832)
    print('read GIS data from PostGIS complete')
    conn.commit()
    gis_data_fr = gis_data
```

This resulted in the following error, telling me that the column geom of the `gis_data` does not exist:

```
  File "<ipython-input-39-3547a1c819b4>", line 10, in <module>
    gis_data = gpd.read_postgis('select precipitat, temperatur, slope, tkle_nr, clc from "gis_data"', conn, geom_col='geom', crs=25832)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\sql.py", line 65, in read_postgis
    raise ValueError("Query missing geometry column '{}'".format(geom_col))

ValueError: Query missing geometry column 'geom'
```

I don't understand why the `geom` column is missing or how to add it.

---

Update:
When I understand it correctly I have to use `ST_Intersection` and `ST_Intersect` in the same query. So I select the intersected geometries from `ST_Intersection`. I have tried this in several ways, but I am unable to find a suitable solution. This is my approach, that I think is closest to the solution

```
sql = 
'CREATE TABLE gis_data AS 
SELECT tps.precipitat, tps.temperatur, tps.slope, bc.tkle_nr, bc.clc, ST_intersection(tps.geom, bc.geom) 
From "temperature_precipation_slope" tps, "buek200_clc10" bc 
WHERE ST_Intersects(tps.geom, bc.geom);'
cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I don't see any call to a geometry column in your CREATE TABLE query's SELECT statement. You would need to add a geometry column in the SELECT statement, depending on which geometry you want to retreive, did you want to fetch the intersected geometry, or the original geometry?

Comment: I want to fetch the intersected geometry. How would I implement the call?
Thanks!

Comment: I basically want the same result as with the Join Attributes by Location Feature in QGIS.

Comment: The Join Attributes by Location keeps the initial geometry, though. If you want the intersected geometry, then try with `CREATE TABLE gis_data AS SELECT tps.precipitat, tps.temperatur, tps.slope, bc.tkle_nr, bc.clc, ST_intersection(tps.geom, bc.geom) as geom From "temperature_precipation_slope" tps, "buek200_clc10" bc WHERE ST_Intersects(tps.geom, bc.geom);`

Comment: Using 'as geom' here is key, otherwise you end up with an unnamed column

Comment: You should always test your PostGIS queries with PGAdmin first.  Other than that, I believe your spacing is incorrect.  Shouldn't the gis_data = gpd.read_postgis line be indented so it is inside the if perform_spatial_join == True: block?

Comment: I added the 'as geom' and the spacing must have been a copy-and-paste error.